# clang 3.2 fails on std::atomic -- a libc++ issue?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, atomic, libc++

I try to compile the simple code

```
#include <atomic>
int bar = 0;
void foo(std::atomic<int>&flag)
{ bar = flag; }
```

with clang++ 3.2 (downloaded as llvm 3.2 from llvm.org; on mac os.x 10.8.3 this fails with the error

> /> clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -O3 -march=native -c test.cc
>
> In file included from test.cc:1:
>
> /usr/include/c++/v1/atomic:576:17: error: first argument to atomic operation must be a pointer to non-const _Atomic type ('const _Atomic(int) *' invalid)
>
> ```
> {return __c11_atomic_load(&__a_, __m);}
>         ^                 ~~~~~
> ```
>
> /usr/include/c++/v1/atomic:580:53: note: in instantiation of member function 
>   'std::_*1::*_atomic_base::load' requested here
>
> ```
> operator _Tp() const _NOEXCEPT          {return load();}
>                                                 ^
> ```
>
> test.cc:5:9: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::_*1::*_atomic_base::operator int' requested here
>
> ```
> bar = done;
> ```

When I use /usr/bin/clang++ instead (which comes with the OS or Xcode) it compiles just fine. The libc++ is that at /usr/lib/c++/v1 in both cases.

What am I missing? Is there another libc++ that comes with llvm 3.2 but which I'm missing? (I cannot find anything in the clang3.2 tree).

Comment: It rather seems like a library issue (spurious `const`) here. And no, libc++ comes within the LLVM umbrella so you should have the right one.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I don't understand. the libc++ at /usr/include/c++/v1 did not come with the llvm3.2 download, but with the OS. Yet xcode seems to have its own version (see answer). so what do you mean with "umbrella"

Comment: LLVM is an open-source project with a (relatively) clear goal, the LLVM umbrella refers to projects related to LLVM; mostly those projects are hosted within the LLVM SVN server. Clang, libc++ and lldb can be thought of as being hosted by LLVM for example. So, that being said, you might have a new LLVM and be using NOT the libc++ that is adapted for it but instead another libc++ lying around somewhere on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode now bundles libc++ within the Xcode.app directory.  You can inspect this directory by control-clicking Xcode.app and choose "Show Package Contents".

Comment: There is indeed another libc++ at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/c++/v1/` (strange directory name with *Toolchains*) and its `atomic` differs by having `__a_` declared as mutable. And this solves the problem. What I still don't get, is why there are these two different versions on my laptop. Are there also different versions of the abi?

Comment: Xcode changed the location of libc++, from /usr/include to internal.  Likely the installer left /usr/include instead of deleting it.  The same abi, __1, is still current.